# Sumproduct or sumif with substitute and criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am struggling on a Excel formula I hope someone can help me with.

Here is what I want to do. I have the following line:

```
|3RO|5R|10RO| |3P|
```

I want to add all the number that goes before a "RO" string, without having the R or blank or P included.

In that case, the result I want is : 13 (3+10)

I have the following:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NUMBERVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(A1:D1,"RO","")))
```

That works if I only have empty or RO containing cells, but of course doesn't work if I have a "5R" value for example

So I would like to first check if the cells value contains "RO", then parse and add

I tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT((RIGHT(A1:E1,2)="RO")*(NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(A1:E1,FIND("RO",;A1:E1)-1))))
```

But it doesn't work either.

Can someone help?

Thanks,

(I hope the formulas are correct, I am "translating" them from french...)

Basically the need is to check / parse / sum all in one... Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps this as an array formula (must be confirmed with Ctrl+Shift+Enter instead of just Enter): `=SUM(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RO",A1:E1)),--SUBSTITUTE(A1:E1,"RO",""),0))`

Comment: That is brilliant, thank you. I didn't knew the array formulas. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

First put this User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function NumPart(rng As Range)
    Dim r As Range, CH As String
    Dim temp As String, K As Long
    Dim arr, L As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(1 To 1, 1 To rng.Count)

    K = 1
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        L = Len(v)
        temp = ""
        For i = 1 To L
            CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
            If CH Like "[0-9]" Then
                temp = temp & CH
            End If
        Next i
        arr(1, K) = CLng(temp)
        K = K + 1
    Next r
    NumPart = (arr)
End Function
```

*(it returns the value of mixed text as Long)*

Then in some cell, enter:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(numpart(A1:D1)*(RIGHT(A1:D1,2)="RO"))
```

[image]